# How do I make an ACCDE file when the original project is too large

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a client who needs to ensure that the system cannot be compromised from a 'disgruntled employee' - ie taking a copy of the 'front end' (the data is not a problem, it is the actual workings and coding that needs to be secured.
The current system is too large to make an ACCDE file (40,000kb).

I have tried reducing, compacting etc. No Joy
I also tried creating a brand new copy and re-importing all modules and objects. No Joy
I then tried creating a blank database with only 1 form and some code to undertake the importing of the objects. The code worked fine. 
The file with just the form and code worked in creating the ACCDE file but the code then failed to run as it is 'transferring objects' and ACCDE files will not allow that.
Are there any alternatives to solve the original problem?
Thank you

Comment: Note that compiling an Access VB project provides very little security in terms of protecting the inner workings of the code. See [this example of the difference between original and compiled + reverse engineered code](https://www.everythingaccess.com/mdeconversion_example.htm). It makes it harder to steal the code, but far from impossible.

Comment: You could split the database into one for the frontend (local tables, queries, forms, reports, macros) and one for code modules.

Comment: Also, if not already done, you could use form instances instead of native copies for different purposes of the 'same' form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are creating `ACCDE` file, be sure to check if project is compilable:

[image]

After this, you'll get errors, that prevents you to create `ACCDE` file.

Other point is that if you are using other files as source libraries (through References), then you should compile them also. `ACCDE` would accept only `ACCDE` files as Access files as library sources.

Anyway, just try first solution, it should help you as I think. Because 40 Mb - not a size for `ACCDE`. Only limitations I know: not more than 1000 objects in database, not more 2 Gb database size for 32 bit Access.

Answer (score 1):

Van Ng - Thank you.
I missed the obvious - after checking if the project using 'Compile Project...' I found some old, redundant code that I had left in with a variable that had not been declared.
I have fixed that and it compiled.

Problem Solved - many thanks.

Comment: It has remembered me same situation, and that I was novice, and there was no SO available... I've cut 50% of modules, see if it is compiled, if not, that this 50 modules divided again... Until I've learned the possibility of compiling via this button, and see exactli where error is present. It was hilarious moment!

Comment: Ouch :) @VanNg. The first thing I do when working with a new Office installation is to add the "Compile" button to the default VBE toolbar.